# SQL Query Execution Plan and Performance difference between 2 servers but query is same

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Problem I am trying to solve is a query that on one server executes in 1 second but on another server it takes 10-20 seconds. Server one is a nightly replication of server 2 so pretty much everything is the same between the 2. Query is the same, underlying view is the same, underlying tables are same.

Looking at the Execution Plan on Server 2 (slow) I see "Filter" after the "Compute Scalar" step which appears to take ~9 seconds. This looks like the only difference because Server 1 execution plan result doesn't have that.

Server 2 (Slow Execution)
[image]

Server 1 (Fast Execution)
[image]

If I hover over the "Filter" step this is what is shows:

[image]

The query that creates this execution is:

```
    SELECT
    FORMAT([Date],'MM-dd-yy') AS [Date],
    [Asia Pacific] AS [Asia Pac],
    India AS [India],
    Europe AS [Europe],
    [North America] AS [N America]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT [Day Type Sort], [Date], Building_Region, CAST([Employee ID] as varchar) AS [Employee ID]
    FROM dbo.View_Name
    WHERE [Day Type Sort] IN ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07')
    AND Building_Region IS NOT NULL
    ) A
    PIVOT
    (
    COUNT([Employee ID]) FOR Building_Region IN([Asia Pacific],India, [Europe], [North America])
    ) B
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

The view has multiple UNIONs with other tables, various calculations, etc...
However as mentioned the final query, view, tables, indexes is all the same between the 2 servers but the execution is not and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your statistics and therefore SQL Server's guess of data thruput are way off, try updating statistics with fullscan on the queried tables.

Comment: I tried UPDATE STATISTICS <Table Name> WITH FULLSCAN for all tables used in the view. That didn't help. Also tried OPTION (RECOMPILE) in the query. That didn't help either.

Comment: What the heck is all that `CASE WHEN len(isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR...` stuff in that predicate on your execution plan? It seems likely you should show us the definitions of your views and tables if we're to offer meaningful help. Please [edit] your question to tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

Does both of your servers have same SQL version and same compatibility mode? If not, that here might be why you have different execution plans.

Please note that your server spent 8s on previous steps and they are not same in both plans.

In first plan your server processed 350k rows, while on second it was only 8.7k so filtering was done on earlier stages in plan.

Please paste entire plan for further analysis

Comment: The 2 servers are absolutely the same and replicate to create a failover group. Also as of now the query is back to running "normally". Nothing was done from the SQL code side. The filter that appeared in the execution plan is no longer there.